# Floating div's in list items (ul, li)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a list with two `<div>`s in every `<li>` and I want to float them one next to the other and I want the `<li>` to take the whole availabe space. How do I do it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
            }
            ul {
            }
            li {
            }
            .a {
            }
            .b {
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="a">
                    content
                </div>
                <div class="b">
                    content
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
 *{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}
 li{  width: 100%: display: block; } 
 li:after{ clear: both; } 
 div.a{ width: 49%;  float: left; }
 div.b{ width: 49%;  float: left; }
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For the divs, you just need to float left and the li, you want to do a clear.  So:

```
li
{
    clear: left;
}
.a
{
    float: left;
}
.b
{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You have to specify a width on floated elements otherwise you won't get the 2-column effect you're after. 49.9% or something should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old post but if someone runs into the same issue think about this:

```
<div>A block-level section in a document</div>
<span>An inline section in a document</span>
```

You can use **span** instead of **div**

To get a **div** besides the other or horizontally you have to apply brute force with .**css** but if you use **span** it will naturally. Copy and paste the following code in a **html** and see what I'm talking about:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <div style="background-color:red">red</div>
      <div style="background-color:blue">blue</div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <span style="background-color:red">red</span>
      <span style="background-color:blue">blue</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also, at least for Microsoft `<li><div></div></li>` won't validate.

Answer (score 0):

Without checking to make sure, this should work

```
LI { width: 100%; }
.a { float: left; }
.b { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
li { width: 100%;}
.a { float: left;}
.b { float: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by take the whole space you mean a width of 100%. I would also assume that you do not want styling applied to the list, which is why I have removed it in this example. This is also hack-free. You need not clear anything, so long as your list item has a width and the overflow: hidden property/value pair.

```css
ul,
li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    overflow: hidden;
}
li div.a,
li div.b {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
li{width:100%;}
.a{}
.b{float: left;}
```

That should do as required from my knowledge of CSS