# float un-ordered list items(ul) next to one another

Tags: asp.net, html, css, stylesheet

I wanna place two child un-ordered lists side by side.
They are having Class Names L and R

Heres the relevant part of the HTML markup.

```
<ul class="SearchResult">
<li class="Pagination">
<a id="lnkPageNumber_top_1" class="ACTIVE" onclick="ShowPage(this.id);" style="cursor: pointer;">1</a>
<a id="lnkPageNumber_top_2" onclick="ShowPage(this.id);" style="cursor: pointer;">2</a>
</li>
<li>
<ul class="L">
<li style="border: medium none ;">
</li>
<li class="Pagination">
<a id="lnkImagePageNumber_1" class="ACTIVE" onclick="ShowImage(this.id);" style="cursor: pointer;">1</a>
<a id="lnkImagePageNumber_2" onclick="ShowImage(this.id);" style="cursor: pointer;">2</a>
<a id="lnkImagePageNumber_3" onclick="ShowImage(this.id);" style="cursor: pointer;">3</a>
<a id="lnkImagePageNumber_4" onclick="ShowImage(this.id);" style="cursor: pointer;">4</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="R">
<li class="T">Rose Villa</li>
<li>
<span>
<strong>Price</strong>
: Rs. 2,000,000
</span>
</li>
<li>
<strong>Features</strong>
:
<img height="16" width="16" src="bed.png" alt="Beds:" title="Bedrooms"/>
3
<img height="16" width="16" src="bath.png" alt="Baths:" title="Bathrooms"/>
3
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The styleSheet applied is this

```
ul.SearchResult { width:100%; list-style:none; }
ul.SearchResult li { margin:2px; height:200px; border:solid 1px #B5D335;clear:left; }
ul.SearchResult img { padding:0px; margin:0px; width:235px; height:156px; border:none }
ul.SearchResult li.Pagination { padding:5px; height:auto; }
ul.SearchResult li.Pagination a { color:#669900; font-weight:bold; }
ul.SearchResult li.Pagination a:hover { color:#FF9900; }
ul.SearchResult li.Pagination a.ACTIVE { color:#FF9900; border:solid 1px #B5D335; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px; }
ul.SearchResult li ul {float:left; list-style:none; }
ul.SearchResult li ul.L { width:245px;} /* Set as Television set BG */
ul.SearchResult li ul.R { width:292px;}
ul.SearchResult li ul li { padding:3px; border:none; height:auto; border-bottom:dotted 1px #C9C9C9; }
ul.SearchResult li ul li.T { text-transform:uppercase; color:#44962A; font-weight:bold }
ul.SearchResult li ul li span { display:table-cell; min-width:125px; width:auto; }
ul.SearchResult li ul li a { color:#44962A; }
ul.SearchResult li ul li a:hover { color:#FF9900; }
```

But the side by side alignment is not working at all.
What could be wrong?
h?
P.S: and yeah, I saw [floating divs in list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93625/float-divs)
Its DIV mentioned there and ul here. Is "clear:left" applicable for bot?

It may be duplicate post for experts in CSS, but I am not. So please bear with it [:)]

Edit Note:- To explain the stuff in detail heres an image
[alt text http://www.yetanothercoder.com/img.jpg](http://www.yetanothercoder.com/img.jpg)

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to do, but it looks fine to me. I tried IE7 and Firefox, and both showed the "1 2 3 4" links next to the "ROSE VILLA" section. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Crumley:- I hope things are more clear now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a clear:none to your UL's should sort it, so:

```
ul.SearchResult li ul {float:left; clear:none; list-style:none; }
```

floating will position the element, but to let other elements position next to it as oppose to underneath it you need to apply the clear:none :)

hope this helps!